# How can I display the function name in vim-airline?

Tags: vim, plugins, statusbar, vim-airline

I'm using the `ctags` vim plugin to have the name of the current C function (=where the cursor is) displayed in the status line.

Today I installed the vim-airline plugin. Fancy, but the C function name is no longer displayed in the status line. There is lots of room for more text. Is there a way to make `ctags.vim` and `airline` coexist or some other technique to show the function name somewhere in the status line like ctags does?

I searched the `:help airline` for `function` but that did not answer my question.

Comment: You should try [airline isssue tracker](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline/issues).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know about `ctags.vim` but vim-airline has support for `tagbar` which is great. You only need to install it ([majutsushi/tagbar](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar)) and then enable it in your `.vimrc` so airline can show you in which function you are on:

```
let g:airline#extensions#tagbar#enabled = 1
```

Of course, in addition to that, you get all the cool functionality of `tagbar`.

Comment: Thanks!!  I spent a while trying to get this to work before finally launching tagbar to saw that I'd broken tagbar with a bad path for ctags.  Once I had tagbar working, the function name showed up in airline.  Yes, very similar in behavior to ctags.vim.