# Customize airline tagbar extension to include current tags parent

Tags: python, vim, ctags, vim-airline, tagbar

The [airline plugin](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline/) has an extension which uses [Tagbar](https://majutsushi.github.io/tagbar/) to show the current function name.

<sup>(I know this because of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789467/how-can-i-display-the-function-name-in-vim-airline) which I found via asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699049/display-current-function-in-vim-status-line))</sup>

This works really well and looks great. Here's airline showing me I'm editing the `do_foo()` function:
[image: airline tagbar extension and the do_foo() function]

But `Tagbar` knows much more than this! Specifically, it knows the current class (i.e. the parent of the current tag):

[image: Tagbar and the DoesFoo class]

<sup>(It does this using [ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags))</sup>

Is there a way to configure `airline` to tell me the current class *as well as* the current function?

Comment: Do you mean  something like `let g:airline#extensions#tagbar#flags = 'f'` (it displays the full hierarchy of the tag, not just the tag itself)?

Comment: @ryuichiro That's it!! Exactly what I've been looking for! Where is the documentation for this?

Comment: You can find it in vim-airline [doc](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline/blob/master/doc/airline.txt#L345). The explanation of flags is in tagbar [doc](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar/blob/master/doc/tagbar.txt#L817). If you have the plugins installed properly, you can get to it in Vim with `:h airline-tagbar`, and `:h tagbar-statusline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full start-to-finish process:

Install universal-ctags: `apt-get install universal-ctags` or alternative
Add these lines in your init.vim / .vimrc, doing an update with your package manager.

```
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'preservim/tagbar'
...
let g:airline#extensions#tagbar#enabled = 1                                                                                                                                                                   
let g:airline#extensions#tagbar#flags = 'f'
```